How Stellar Spectral Types are assigned
I am working with data from the NASA Exoplanet Archive. From my understanding, stars are assigned spectral types (O, B, A, F, G, K, M) based primarily on stellar temperature. ref
However, I’ve noticed some mismatches when comparing the stellar temperatures in the data to their assigned spectral types. For instance, a star with a temperature of 4874 K, which I would expect to be classified as a K-type star, but in the dataset, it is listed as a G-type star.
Am I misunderstanding how the classification correlates with stellar temperatures? Is there another factor in the classification process that I might be missing.
Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated!

Stars are assigned (MK) spectral types by looking at their spectra. To be specific, by looking at their spectra in the spectral classification wavelength band - basically blue and green light. You are right that this strongly correlates with temperature. Surface gravity and metallicity can play a role.

okay that makes sense. so ill be unable to get correct class with only temp and other data. i need the spectral band too?

Well you can estimate what the spectral class is if you have a temperature (there are no estimated temperatures that are accurate to 4 significant figures). But you have to be aware that this estimate might be in error if the star is (a) not a main sequence star or (b) has an unusual composition. If you know that the star is not on the main sequence, but is say a giant, then you should use a SpT-Teff relationship that is appropriate for giants. Note that "K-type" is not really a spectral classification. It should be something like K2V or K5III or similar.
